# How to break a range down into smaller non-overlapping ranges

Tags: ruby

What is the most beautiful way to break a larger range into smaller non overlapping ranges?

```
range = 1..375
```

Desired Output:

```
1..100
101..200
201..300
301..375
```

Comment: Does `range.begin` always equal one? If not, and `range = 150..375` do you want the decomposed ranges to be `150..249`, `250..349`, `350..375`? Is the size of each decomposed range but the last `100`, regardless of the size of the range?

Comment: No the range can start with any number and just goes up by whatever interval you want to specify.

Comment: I suggest you incorporate your comment in your question and then we delete the comments.

Comment: My understanding is ActiveSupport extends Ruby for methods common to Rails users. This may be an extension to add to ActiveSupport?

Comment: Good point @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) in combination with [`#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
(1..375).each_slice(100).map { |a,*,b| (a..b) }     

#=> [1..100, 101..200, 201..300, 301..375]
```

Comment: Woah! Whats up with the splat in the mapped arguments? I don't even understand how thats working!

Comment: @TomRossi Basically you're splitting each element passed to the block in three parts where the first part is the first element (`a`), the third part is the last element (`b`) and all elements between the first and the last element are the second part which isn't really used here. You could also do something like this `|a, *x, b|`, in this case all the elements between `a` and `b` would be assigned to the `x` variable and you could of course use the `x` variable, which stores all the elements between `a` and `b`, inside the block.

Comment: You can try out different combinations like `|a, b, c ,d, *|` or `|*, a, b, c, d|` and see the results, I think that would demonstrate it pretty good :) For example, try printing out the value of `a`, `b`,`c` and `d` in these examples and see what happens.

Comment: Instead of explaining how the code works in a comment, put the explanation into the answer. That makes it obvious for others looking for the solution.

Comment: This is a nice answer but it does have the disadvantage of requiring `map` to create and discard temporary arrays `[2,3,...,99]`, `[101,102,...,199]` and so on. If there is any question that that is happening, note the following: `n = 1_000_000_000_000;  (1..n).each_slice(n/2).map { |a,*,b| (a..b) } #=> NoMemoryError (failed to allocate memory)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the comment, you're right, that is definitely a downside of my solution. I will leave my solution as it is as your answer provides a different approach that solves the issue.

Comment: It is only a downside if the range is large. It does read nicely—better than my solution—and would not be a problem if the range were of modest size.

Comment: How does the overhead of this solution compare to the original? I like the concise nature, but I am working with huge ranges.

Answer (score 2):

The following may not be the most elegant solution but it is designed to be relatively efficient, by avoiding the creation of temporary arrays.

```
def divide_range(range, sz)
  start = range.begin
  (range.size/sz).times.with_object([]) do |_,arr|
    arr << (start..start+sz-1)
    start += sz
  end.tap { |arr| (arr << (start..range.end)) if start < range.end }
end
```

```
divide_range(1..375, 100)
  #=> [1..100, 101..200, 201..300, 301..375] 
divide_range(1..400, 100)
  #=> [1..100, 101..200, 201..300, 301..400] 
divide_range(50..420, 50)
  #=> [50..99, 100..149, 150..199, 200..249, 250..299, 300..349,
  #    350..399, 400..420]
n = 1_000_000_000_000
divide_range(1..n, n/2)
  #=> [1..500000000000, 500000000001..1000000000000]
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than the solution I started with?

Comment: Somewhat red-faced I must confess I did not read your code very carefully. My answer is only a slight variant of yours, certainly not better than yours. Your use of `step`, for one, is an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I'm using the `step` method, but I don't like having to check the top of the range and do calculations to avoid overlapping:

For example:

```
range = 1..375
interval = 100
range.step(interval).each do |start|
  stop = [range.last, start + (interval - 1)].min
  puts "#{start}..#{stop}"
end
```

I've taken this code and extended `Range` as well:

```
class Range
  def in_sub_ranges(interval)
    step(interval).each do |start|
      stop = [range.last, start + (interval - 1)].min
      yield(start..stop)
    end
  end
end
```

This allows me to do

```
range.in_sub_ranges(100) { |sub| puts sub }
```

Comment: Why not just `range.step(interval).map {|i| i..[i+interval-1, range.last].min }` ?

Comment: @ChrisHeald I like the use of Array#min!